# Struct Node in tree class is not being recognized when I compile

Tags: c++

I get this error from the compiler (I get like 5 of these errors):

```
./Tree.h:14:2: error: unknown type name 'Node'
         Node *getParent(Node *child);
```

Here is my `Tree.h` class:

```
#ifndef TREE_H_    
#define TREE_H_

class Tree {
public:
    Tree(int arr []);
    Node *getParent(Node *child);
    Node *getRightChild(Node *parent);
    Node *getLeftChild(Node *parent);
private:
    struct Node {
        Node *parent;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        int value;
    };
    Node *root;
    int size;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get this code to compile is to forward declare `Node`:

```
class Tree {
private:                      // add this
    struct Node;              // and this
public:
    Tree(int arr []);
    Node *getParent(Node *child);
    Node *getRightChild(Node *parent);
    Node *getLeftChild(Node *parent);
private:
    struct Node {
        Node *parent;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        int value;
    };
    Node *root;
    int size;
};
```

This works because you are only using pointers-to-Node (`Node *`) in your outer class.  If you wanted to use a bare `Node` then you would have to use the other solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the arrangement of code to this and it should work fine:

```cpp
#ifndef TREE_H_
#define TREE_H_

class Tree {
private:
    struct Node {
        Node *parent;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        int value;
    };

    Node *root;
    int size;

public:
    Tree(int arr []);
    Node *getParent(Node *child);
    Node *getRightChild(Node *parent);
    Node *getLeftChild(Node *parent);
};
```

The compiler reads the code in sequence. In your case, you have defined your `Node` struct after defining your functions (which are using instances of your `Node` struct) and hence, it is unable to recognize the `Node` type.

Declaring your `Node` struct before declaring your functions will make your code work.

Comment: so if I want the Node struct to be private would I have to switch the private and public sections of the class so it reads it first?

Comment: @boogiewoogie You can have multiple public and/or private sections.

Comment: Okay I see now. I was just wondering what good syntax would be for this addition. So do you think adding in a private section with the Node struct as first thing in the class be acceptable syntax?

Comment: With this as it stands, no client would be able to use the return value from any of the methods.  You need to make `Node` public and the class clients would use `Tree::Node*` instances - see https://godbolt.org/z/7PvG51jTd

Comment: If you don't want public access to the tree nodes, you would need to create a tree-browser which iterates its position through the tree, returning values as opposed to nodes.  The tree-browser would need to be a friend class of the tree.